# Python- Conditional formatting on date column in Excel

Tags: python, excel, date, conditional-formatting

I am trying to highlight the cells which are latest than the date am passing as input (Kind of finding the due date scenario).

```
writer.sheets[sheet_name].conditional_format('H:H',
                                                          {'type': 'date',
                                                           'criteria': 'between',
                                                           'minimum':  ip_date,
                                                           'maximum':  datetime.datetime.strptime('9999-01-01','%Y-%m-%d'),
                                                           'format': latest_format})
```

Getting the error - 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

Can anyone help with a solution to this scenario

Thank you

Comment: share code and error log

Comment: It would be great to get a solution to just highlight dates which is latest than a particular date. I am passing the date to compare as input to the code. Any leads are appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55966691 i hope this will help you